# How to order descending the data in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to order the data descending in hibernate,
but not working at all,

this is my code,

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<MPNValas> listAllMPNValas() throws Exception{
    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(MPNValas.class);
    criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("ID"));
    List<MPNValas> mpnvalasList = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
    return mpnvalasList;
}
```

this is my controller,

```
@RequestMapping("/admin/mpn-valas.html")
public ModelAndView listMPNValas(ModelMap model)throws Exception
{
    User user           = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    String sessionUser  = user.getUsername();

    try{
        UserAdmin dataUser = userService.get(sessionUser);
        model.addAttribute("userData", dataUser);
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("mpnvalas");
    List<MPNValas> mpnvalas = mpnvalasService.listAllMPNValas();
    mav.addObject("mpnvalas", mpnvalas);
    return mav;

}
```

and this is the class,

```
package prod.support.model.gwprod;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="LOOKUP")
public class MPNValas {

private Integer ID;
private String TIPE;
private String KODE_PERUSAHAAN;
private String CODE;
private String NAME;
private String VALUE;

@Id
@Column(name="ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
public Integer getID() {
    return ID;
}
public void setID(Integer ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}
@Column(name="TIPE")
public String getTIPE() {
    return TIPE;
}
public void setTIPE(String TIPE) {
    this.TIPE = TIPE;
}
@Column(name="KODE_PERUSAHAAN")
public String getKODE_PERUSAHAAN() {
    return KODE_PERUSAHAAN;
}
public void setKODE_PERUSAHAAN(String KODE_PERUSAHAAN) {
    this.KODE_PERUSAHAAN = KODE_PERUSAHAAN;
}
@Column(name="CODE")
public String getCODE() {
    return CODE;
}
public void setCODE(String CODE) {
    this.CODE = CODE;
}
@Column(name="NAME")
public String getNAME() {
    return NAME;
}
public void setNAME(String NAME) {
    this.NAME = NAME;
}
@Column(name="VALUE")
public String getVALUE() {
    return VALUE;
}
public void setVALUE(String VALUE) {
    this.VALUE = VALUE;
}



/**
 * @param args
 */

}
```

and this the list of data

[image: list data]

that I miss something??

any help will be pleasure :))

Comment: What do you mean it is not working? What happens when you run this code? Turn on SQL logging to see the actual query being sent to database.

Comment: Like your problem I have a problem but in mine first of all my getting data from database like yours but than I did some changes this list and result to other list and etc.In the new list the order was changed.Are you sure you are using same list which you get from database?

Comment: @PredragMaric I mean the list of my data not sort by descending like I want

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli Yeah, I'm sure, what should I do??

Comment: Your controllor is correct.Please show us MPNValas Pojo

Answer (score 3):

You miss nothing, just note that the argument to the *desc* method is case sensitive and should match the name of the attribute to sort by.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Foo.class, "FOO");
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("id"));
```

Comment: still not working, dude... the list of my data still in ascending... ~

Comment: have you tried with a HQL query to see if something else is wrong?

Comment: yet, but I have edited my post... anything wrong in my controller??